# Android Material BottomNavigationView badge not avail

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

According to Official documentations, [Link1](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/) & [Link2](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomNavigationView.md#badges), the Material BottomNavBar can have a badge attached to any of its menu items. Having said that, from the above documentations the badge is not created/removed from BottomNavBar id rather it is associated with `BottomNavigationView`.

Can any guide what is `BottomNavigationView` and how to get the badge for same?

Comment: But what is the issue with the BottomNavigationView and the badge?

Comment: the badge options( get/remove) are not available when tried with bottomNavBarId.get...

Comment: with version of the material components are you using?

Comment: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: You need 1.1.0. currently 1.1.0-beta02

Comment: Thanks, Gabriele. It worked, was just a matter of version.